# IE browser cache not clearing after reload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dojo

IE browser  cache not clearing after reloading the page.

**Actual result:**

we  are using dojo filtering and at very first time login to the application data is showing properly and I tried to change option in combo as per that data has to be display but in my case page is reloading and previous data it is showing .I have tried below  settings change option then it is working fine.

https://superuser.com/questions/81182/how-to-force-internet-explorer-ie-to-really-reload-the-page

Select Tools >> Internet Options.
Click the Settings button in Browsing History.
Select the Every time I visit the webpage radio button.
Click OK to close the Settings dialog.
Click OK to close the Internet Options dialog.

**Expected result**

Without changing the browser settings   it should be  displayed fresh data with on change of dojo combo and it should not display previous data.

code:

```
function setNamespaceMode(selection)   
        {
             console.log( "Setting namespace mode:" + selection.value + " from " + dojo.cookie("cmdb.mode.namespaceID"));
              if (  dojo.cookie("cmdb.mode.namespaceID") != selection.value ) {
                dojo.cookie("cmdb.mode.namespaceID",selection.value, { path: '/cmdb/'});
                dojo.cookie("cmdb.mode.namespace",selection.textbox.value, { path: '/cmdb/'});
                var url = window.location.href.split("#"); // 'Bookmarked' URLs don't come back to server on a refresh so strip the bookmark part
                console.log("refresh url " + url[0]);
               window.location.href=url[0]; // refresh the page with the namespace filter applied
            } 
        }
**Jsp code:**
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" href="/cmdb/coherence/cache?ccType=${ipccClassName}" >
        </div>
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" href="/cmdb/coherence/cache?ccType=${extClassName}" >
        </div>
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" href="/cmdb/coherence/cache?ccType=${proxyClassName}" >
```

Comment: "Without changing the browser settings" --> "How can I see without eyes?" User controls the browser settings, and caching in IE is controlled by browser settings, you can't fork that.

Comment: Try adding a query string to the URL used to refresh the page

Comment: I have fixed this issue by passing querystring as timestamp. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

To avoid browser cache problems you can do:

- At the client side add an extra parameter to your url, for example with the current time. [dojo/request](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/request.html) and some other dojo modules have the `preventCache` option, which does that.
- Configure the web server to set the `cache-control` or `Expires` HTTP headers for the urls that should not be cached.